# Multiple Selection QTreeWidget

Tags: select, pyqt, qlistwidget, qtreewidget

Does anyone know if its possible to select multiple items on a QTreeWidget and how to go about enabling the multiple selection?

All the items I want to be selectable are top level QTreeWidgetItems and all their children are set to be disabled (i.e QTreeWidgetItem.setDisabled(True) )

Comment: HA! Found it ->

QTreeWidgetItem.setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection ) 

I found that bit of code while trying to make a multi selectable QListW

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is, you'll want to call [setSelectionMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionMode-prop) during init to enable QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection. QTreeView/QTreeWidget inherit QAbstractItemView, so it is available.

Then to disable the items, just hook on to QTreeWidgets.itemSelectionChanged() signal.

Comment: Thanks... I managed to find the answer already but since I dont have enough points I couldn't answer my own question so I just left a comment answering it. Thanks for taking the time though :) Its very appreciated

Comment: Link is ded. But official docs are here anyway: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionMode-prop

Answer (score 1):

I think below will help:

```
youQTreeWidget.setSelectionMode(QGui.QAbstractView.MultiSelection)
```

Comment: It should be `QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection`